# How to apply Buoyant force to a Box2d body?

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I have been following a formula to calculate the buoyant force needed to apply to a dynamic body to be able to simulate water.

> Fb = ρgV

1. Fb - is the buoyant force
2. ρ - density of the liquid
3. g - gravity
4. V - volume of the object

My box2d body will always be submerged to the sensor so I don't have to detect what portion of the body is in the water, basically the entire body is always in the water and I will always apply the force to the center of the body.

```
body.applyForceTocenter(0, Fb, true);
```

If I apply the force on upon collision to the censor then it will just fall cause there is not enough force, and if I type this to the render method then the body will fly cause there is too much force. So how do I implement the force? and how to compute for the drag? so that it won't bounce.

Comment: Its for Unity but this talk explains buoyancy pretty generically. Might help. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OOeA0pJ8Y2s

Answer (score 1):

Your primary question is:

> So how do I implement the force?

Considering that your body is always underwater, there's an easy way out of this one: just use gravity :) As iforce2d points out [in his tutorial on custom gravity](http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/custom-gravity), you can set the gravity scale of any object:

```
//Box2D v2.2.1 onwards
body->SetGravityScale(0);//cancel gravity (use -1 to reverse gravity, etc)
```

So if you can control the bouyant force by tweaking the value you pass to [`setGravityScale`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Body.html#setGravityScale-float-). As long as it's less than 0 your object will be bouyant.

As usual if you want your body to experience drag then use [`setLinearDamping`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Body.html#setLinearDamping-float-).

If you want to control the bounce then set the [`restitution`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/FixtureDef.html#restitution) field to some value between 0 and 1 when you create the fixture, or use the appropriate method to change it when the fixture has been created.